# Rails - Paperclip url in JSON along with other attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I've followed Ryan Bates' [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) on using jQuery Tokeninput for an auto-completing list for a many-to-many association. Now I want to pull in a photo for each result. I'm using Paperclip and get the url's passed into a JSON file by doing this in the controller:

```
format.json { render :json => @users.map(&:photo_url) }
```

Ryan's code for passing the attributes into a JSON file is this:

```
format.json { render :json => @users.map(&:attributes) }
```

But how can I combine the two to display both the `:attributes` and `:photo_url` methods in the JSON file?

I've tried different things, including the below code, but nothing seems to work. It seems as if there can only be one method called on `.map`?

```
// Doesn't work
format.json { render :json => @users.map(&:attributes, &:photo_url) }

// Doesn't work
format.json { render :json => @users.map(&:attributes).map(&:photo_url) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help? (Note - I'm just returning from a night out and am not 100%, so I might be misunderstanding your question entirely.)

This creates an array of arrays: The first element in the array contains the user's attributes, and the second contains the photo URL:

`@users.map {|u| [u.attributes, u.photo_url]}`

This creates a hash - just like the above array. But the first element is named "attributes" and the second is named "photo_url".

`@users.map {|u| {:attributes => u.attributes, :photo_url => u.photo_url}}`

Try plugging one or both of those in. They should work for you.

(E.g. `format.json { render :json => @users.map {|u| [u.attributes, u.photo_url]} }`).

---

Edit:

Just had another thought.

You can merge the two into one collection (so that you'll have it all in one hash instead of separate elements in an array):

`@users.map {|u| u.attributes.merge(:photo_url => u.photo_url)}`

That'll add `photo_url` as a key to the `attributes` hash. It might work more easily for whatever code you've written to read the JSON.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction for updating this form w/ AJAX, so users don't have to click the 'save' button to update it?

```<%= form_for @project, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>```
```<%= f.text_field :member_tokens, "data-pre" => @project.users.map {|u| u.attributes.merge(:photo_url => u.photo_url)}.to_json %>```
```<%= f.submit :value => "Save", :class => "tagbtn" %>```
```<% end %>```

Answer (score 0):

In case of this being helpful to anyone, i find out a nice way to do this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "500x500#", :medium => "300x300#", :small => "100x100#", :thumb => "50x50#" }

  def as_json(options)
    json = super
    self.avatar.styles.each do | format |
      json = json.merge({"avatar_"+format[0].to_s => self.avatar(format[0])})
    end
    json
  end
end
```

You can then simply call

```
render :json => @my_model
```

Also working while rendering collections.

It is then possible to do some conditional rendering with as_json(options), with something like:

```
model_to_json = @my_model.to_json(:nested => true)
render :json => model_json
```